# How to write insert trigger in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hello I want create one insert trigger in that i have to table that

Table hardwaremaster

```
 hardwareid     hardwarename      quantity
     1             HDD              5          and second table
     2             RAM              2
```

Table transdetails

```
  transid        hardwareid
     1               1
     2               1
     3               1
     4               1
     5               1
     6               2
     7               2
```

Here i want to create trigger in that once value come in hardwaremaster then it will update table transdetails . then how to write trigger in to it

Answer (score 3):

This can help you :

```
 CREATE TRIGGER TR_INS_WhatYouWant
    ON hardwaremaster
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    DECLARE @hardwareid  INT
    SELECT @hardwareid  = hardwareid  FROM inserted
    GO

    INSERT INTO dbo.transdetails (hardwareid) VALUES (@hardwareid)
```

But I suggest to read this before make trigger work :

[CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189799.aspx)